# Generating Symmetric Group from a subset

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Show that Sn (the finite symmetric group)  is generated by the subset
{(1, 2),(2, 3),...,(n − 1, n)} by using the formula σ·(a1,...,ak)·σ−1 = (σ(a1),...,σ(ak))

I know that we can get any k-cycle from this subset but I'm not sure how to choose σ to make use of the formula. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Every permutation can be written as the product of cycles.

Comment: Pick any permutation $\sigma$.  You can move $\sigma(n)$ to $n$ using $(\sigma(n),\sigma(n)+1),\dots,(n-1,n)$, induct.

Comment: @user10354138 I have seen the inductive proof that you mentioned, but the problem is specifically asking for a proof using the given formula.

Comment: In that case use the hint given by @angryavian , you need to show that any transposition $(a,b)$ can be generated from your set, which is (again) shifting the $a,b$ until they are consecutive.

Comment: @user10354138 So I need to show that given any (a,b), I can generate it using only elements from the subset? I've tried to do this but I can't seem to find the right σ and (a1....ak) to produce (a,b)

Comment: Just use the given transpositions.  Example: $(a,a+1)(a+1,a+2)(a,a+1)=((a,a+1)(a+1),(a,a+1)(a+2))=(a,a+2)$ so you can generate $(a,b)$ where $\lvert a-b\rvert=2$.  Repeat.

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks I think I got It now :)